Social Media Listening FB and IG using Graph Explorer
I want to do social media listening for public data on FB and IG using the Graph API, but it's asking for business verification. How do companies get data without scrapers? Any suggestions on accessing data without business verification?
I was unsuccessful using the GRAPH API, due to the requirement of business verification. I am looking to understand how companies do social media listening as it is an integral part right now.

"How do companies get data without scrapers?" - they just do the business verification ...?
